# Enforce Permissions via remote schema in Hasura

Tags: postgresql, permissions, authorization, hasura

I'm unable to enforce Permissions via a Remote Schema Relationship. Is this possible to achieve with Hasura?

I have a Remote Schema defined which contains the following query:

```
type Query
  isAllowed (
    actor: [X-Hasura-User-Id]
    action
    resource
):uuid
```

Example usage:

```
# Returns a UUID if X-Hasura-User-Id can select resource 1234
query IsAllowed {
 isAllowed(action: "select", resource: 1234)
}
```

In another table, I've added a **Remote Schema Relationship** to my remote query: `isAllowed`.

When I visit the **Permissions** tab of that table I'm unable to select the returned `uuid` from `isAllowed` (which is what I require to actually enforce any permissions using this approach).

Is it possible to use a remote schema to enforce permissions?

(My database is currently Postgres 12).